# How to Drag and Drop onto .BAT all while maintaining entire File Name?

Tags: loops, batch-file

I created a small bat that takes folder(s) and/or File(s) and stores the results in a temp file. But I soon found that when trying to drop a file with a !, the ! was lost when the results were put in temp file. I also tried to add tokens and override the default delimiters, but no go for that as well. Any Ideas?

```
::Drag and drop Folder(s) or File(s) stores results in temp txt file
For %%I in (%*) do (
set Drag_Drop_Var!n!=%%I
echo !Drag_Drop_Var0!>>temp123456789.txt
```

So disabling delayed expansion works for retaining the ! but their are cases where I need it enabled and I will lose the !.

```
SET /A Num_lines_b=1 
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%I IN ('type "%cd%%Hash_Database%"') DO ( 
SET Var_from_hash_database!Num_lines_b!=%%I 
SET /a Num_lines_b+=1 
)
```

As you can see with delayed expansion disabled`!Num_lines_b!` variable will be empty.

```
SET /A Num_lines_b=1 
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%I IN ('type "%cd%%Hash_Database%"') DO ( 
CALL SET Var_from_hash_database%Num_lines_b%=%%I 
CALL SET /a Num_lines_b+=1 
)
```

I was able to solve the issue by keeping the delayed expansion disabled and in the FOR loops CALL SET the variables. Thanks for all your help guys.

Comment: Why are you storing them in a pseudo array before outputting them into a file. If you are just going to output them to a file then use the `FOR` variable.

Comment: Your right. Thanks, I went ahead and fixed that, but that still will not fix the issue of a file name loosing an exclamation point during processing. Any thoughts?

Comment: New code snippet. `For %%I in (%*) do echo %%I >>temp123456789.txt`

Comment: It won't lose any exclamations if you don't enable delayed expansion.

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know enabling did that. I do need it enabled for other parts of the .bat, so I just disabled it for that for loop and reenabled after. Works. Thanks.

Comment: Don't have a crystal ball to see your code. You might want to update your question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Edit your question. Don't post that much code in a comment.

Comment: I deleted the comment and updated the question description.

Comment: Enable delayed expansion only when you actually need it; when expanding normal `%`-variables of `for` meta-variables, keep delayed expansion disabled...

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo off 
for %%f in (%1\*.*) do echo %%f>>temp123456789.txt
pause
```

I tried with ! in the filename and they were not lost in the output file.